# Backbone: Wait for multiple fetch to continue

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I fetch collection of multiple pages and I am looking for a way to know when all fetchs are done.
Here is what my collection looks like:

```
app.collections.Repos = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: app.models.Repo,
  initialize: function(last_page){
    this.url = ('https://api.github.com/users/' + app.current_user + '/watched');

    for (var i = 1; i <= last_page; i++) {
      this.fetch({add: true, data: {page: i}});  
    };
  }, ...
```

Any idea how I could achieve this with clean code?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use jQuery [deferreds](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/):

```
var deferreds = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= last_page; i++) {
  deferreds.push(this.fetch({add: true, data: {page: i}}));
};

$.when.apply($, deferreds).done(function() {
  ...
  <CODE HERE>
  ...
}
```

(I haven't actually tested this but I think it should work.)

jQuery documentation on [`when`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/):

> Provides a way to execute callback functions based on one or more objects, usually Deferred objects that represent asynchronous events.

And another answer that might help: [How do you work with an array of jQuery Deferreds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878887/how-do-you-work-with-an-array-of-jquery-deferreds)

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `underscore.js`' `after` -function ([docs](http://underscorejs.org/#after)), but that necessitates using a success -callback, because there will be A LOT of add -events:

```
initialize: function(last_page){
  this.url = ('https://api.github.com/users/' + app.current_user + '/watched');

  var self = this; // save a reference to this

  var successCallback = _.after(function() {

    self.trigger('allPagesFetched'); //trigger event to notify all listeners that fetches are done

  }, last_page); // this function will be called when it has been called last_page times

  for (var i = 1; i <= last_page; i++) {
    this.fetch({add: true, data: {page: i}, success: successCallback});  
  };
},
```

Hope this helped!