# Multiple ajax calls from array and handle callback when completed

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback, deferred

I have used promises in jQuery slightly before - but I am having trouble applying it to this scenario. I prefer to use the $.when() and $.done() methods to achieve this.

From what I understand I need to build a $.Deferred object which logs the requests and when those requests are finished - fire the callback. In my code below the callback is firing *before* the ajax requests and not after - maybe I just need some sleep

I know my code is incomplete I have been struggling to apply it with the addition of the for loop.

http://jsfiddle.net/whiteb0x/MBZEu/

```
var list = ['obj1', 'obj2', 'obj3', 'obj4', 'obj5'];
var callback = function() {
  alert("done");
};
var requests = [];

var ajaxFunction = function(obj, successCallback, errorCallback) {
  for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'url',
      success: function() {
            requests.push(this);
      }
    });
  }
};
$.when($.ajax(), ajaxFunction).then(function(results){callback()});
```

Comment: Look this question to receive all promises like an array
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16208148

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The arguments to `$.when` should be the return value of `$.ajax`, which also doesn't need to be called separately -- that makes no sense.  You want something like this:

```
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
   requests.push($.ajax(...));
}
$.when.apply(undefined, requests).then(...)
```

The reason that `.apply` is needed is because `$.when` can take multiple arguments, but not an array of arguments.  `.apply` expands essentially to:

```
$.when(requests[0], requests[1], ...)
```

This also assumes that the requests can be completed in any order.

http://jsfiddle.net/MBZEu/4/ -- notice that 'done' is logged to the console after all of the success messages.

Comment: how to handle all the results at once?

Comment: $.when.apply(undefined, requests).done(function(response1, response2, ...){ if(response1[1]=="success") {// DoSomething with response1[0]} });

Comment: Still, how to get all the responses in an array? You cannot expect one to know how many responses are going to be there before hand.

Comment: As @MKYung asked, it could be a problem to handle the results... because, if you have just one element in the list of requests you'll got one retuning result in the method `done` but divided into three parameter `jqXHR.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) { ... });`. But with multiple requests you got all the three parameters wrapped in arrays e.g. `jqXHR.done(function( [data, textStatus, jqXHR], [data, textStatus, jqXHR], ... ) { ... });`. To handle it inside the `done` method you have to know the count of requests, in this case `list.length` to decide how to parse the results...

Answer (score 9):

I share an easy example that could help you to handle multiple requests and their responses:

```
var arr = [
    $.ajax({url:"test1.php"}),
    $.ajax({url:"test2.php"}),
    $.ajax({url:"test3.php"})
];
$.when.apply( undefined, arr ).then(function() {
    var objects=arguments;
    console.dir(objects);
});
```