# Using an array of deffered with jQuery.when()

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred, .when

I'm using `$.when` to run 2 functions prior to some other logic. Now, in several cases I need to run a different set of functions prior to doing that same logic, so I wanted to pass an array of the functions to `$.when`, but couldn't make it run.

Something like:

```
function funcA(){
    console.log("funcA");
}
function funcB(){
    console.log("funcB")
}
var funcArr = [funcA, funcB];

$.when(funcArr).then(function(){
    console.log("DONE!");
});
```

But this doesn't work and the only thing written to the console is "DONE!".
I read the following [How do you work with an array of jQuery Deferreds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878887/how-do-you-work-with-an-array-of-jquery-deferreds), but the following behaves the same:

```
$.when.apply($, funcArr).then(function(){
    console.log("DONE!")
});
```

What's wrong there?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inputs to `$.when` aren't of type `Deferred`, which is the expected input type for the function - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

At the simplest level, you could construct `Deferred` types with your functions as the `beforeStart` construction parameters. Like:

```
var funcArr = [$.Deferred(funcA), $.Deferred(funcB)];
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6MeM5/

**Additionally:**

If you're just trying to execute each function in an array of functions, you don't need to get `Deferred` involved. Just iterate the array using `$.each`, like:

```
$.each(funcArr, function(){
    this();
});
```