# $.when() with array of Deferreds not calling done action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I am trying to use a variable set of deferred functions in an array along with `$.when()`. These functions fetch data from the server and render it in the DOM. After all these are done, some scripts are loaded and a couple post-load actions are performed.

Here is what I am using:

```
function loadAllGames(updateGames, updatePlayoffs) {
    var deferredLoads = [];
    if (updateGames !== false)
        deferredLoads.push($.Deferred(loadGames));

    if (updatePlayoffs !== false)
        deferredLoads.push($.Deferred(loadPlayoffs));

    $.when.apply($, deferredLoads).done(loadPostGamesLoadData);
}
```

The problem is that `loadPostGamesLoadData` is never being called.

Both `loadGames` and `loadPlayoffs` return promises:

```
function loadGames() {
    $.get('{% url wave_spinner_template %}', {message: 'Loading games...'}, function (data) {
        $('#weeks').html(data);
    });

    return $.ajax({
        url: "{% url weeks season.id %}",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#weeks').html(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("Error loading games.");
        }
    });
}

function loadPlayoffs() {
    $.get('{% url wave_spinner_template %}', {message: 'Loading playoffs...'}, function (data) {
        $('#playoffs').html(data).children('.spinner-container').addClass('border-top');
    });

    return $.ajax({
        url: "{% url playoffs season.id %}",
        success: function (data) {
            var $playoffs = $('#playoffs');
            if (!$playoffs.length) {
                $playoffs = $('<div>', {id: 'playoffs'});
                $('#weeks').after($playoffs);
            }
            $playoffs.html(data);
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("Error loading playoffs.");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: There are no promises returned.

Comment: it's returning `$.ajax`, all examples I saw used this for returning promises. What should i do instead?

Comment: In the future, just edit your previous question to which was quite incomplete rather than make a whole another question.  You can use the "edit" link to fix up your question at any time.

Comment: @jfriend00: It's a tough call. That question was about why `loadPostGamesLoadData` was called before the deferreds completed, and correctly answered by adeneo. But then that revealed *this* problem, that the deferreds were incorrect and (as of fixing the problem adeneo pointed out) it wasn't getting called *at all*. Questions shouldn't be moving targets ("Okay, I fixed that, but now it's not called at all?!"), so there's a good reason to post a new, separate question. But it's a very fine line, absolutely.

Comment: @jfriend00: I didn't short-circuit anything. I didn't see the previous question at all. I saw, and answered, this one. Then, later, I saw your comment above, got curious, and went looking. Sure, maybe adeneo could have flagged that up and answered both parts (he posted his answer before your comment asking about that), but he didn't, and again questions shouldn't be moving targets. In any case, it's not a big deal.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - OK, I confused you with adeneo.  My comments were mostly directed at him.  But that confusion came because you were defending the previous question as it stands which I obviously disagree with.  Oh well, I've said my piece.  Just trying to teach people to write better questions that show enough to get to the bottom of the whole problem, not peel it like an onion across many questions and not teach the OP anything about writing better questions.  I'm sure you've seen many examples of that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating the deferred objects incorrectly; indeed, you shouldn't be creating them at all. The function accepted by `$.Deferred` is a factory function run just before `$.Deferred` returns which receives the new deferred object as an argument (so you can attach handlers to it). ([Details in the API docs.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/)) That's not what `loadGames` and such do at all; they *return* a deferred object. So you end up with deferred objects that nothing ever settles.

Since they *already* have deferred objects from `$.ajax`, which you're returning, just use those functions directly:

```
function loadAllGames(updateGames, updatePlayoffs) {
    var deferredLoads = [];
    if (updateGames !== false)
        deferredLoads.push(loadGames());
// ------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^

    if (updatePlayoffs !== false)
        deferredLoads.push(loadPlayoffs());
// ------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    $.when.apply($, deferredLoads).done(loadPostGamesLoadData);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Drop the `Deferred` calls, as `$.ajax` already returns a deferred.

```
function loadAllGames(updateGames, updatePlayoffs) {
    var deferredLoads = [];
    if (updateGames !== false)
        deferredLoads.push(loadGames());

    if (updatePlayoffs !== false)
        deferredLoads.push(loadPlayoffs());

    $.when.apply($, deferredLoads).done(loadPostGamesLoadData);
}
```