# jQuery.when not waiting for get to complete

Tags: jquery, promise

I feel like I'm not getting the concept promises here. I'm trying to get external css used in a file and append it to the html. Then I'd like to do something with that content. What all am I doing wrong here? This is where I'm at after flailing and reading the docs for longer than I'd like to admit.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {
            $.when(convertPageCssToInlineStyle()).then(
                alert(document.documentElement.outerHTML)
            );


        });

        var convertPageCssToInlineStyle = function() {
            var links = $("html").find("link[rel=stylesheet]");

            links.attr("href", function(i, value) {
                if (!window.location.origin)
                    window.location.origin = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + value;

                $.when(
                    $.get(window.location.origin, function(response) {
                        $('<style />').text(response).appendTo($('head'));
                    })
                );

            });
        };
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `convertPageCssToInlineStyle` function must return a promise. Right now it isn't returning anything.

Something like this....

```
    $(function() {
        $.when(convertPageCssToInlineStyle()).then(
            alert(document.documentElement.outerHTML)
        );


    });

    var convertPageCssToInlineStyle = function() {
        var links = $("html").find("link[rel=stylesheet]");
        var deferred = $.Deferred();
        links.attr("href", function(i, value) {
            if (!window.location.origin)
                window.location.origin = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + value;

            $.when(
                $.get(window.location.origin, function(response) {
                    $('<style />').text(response).appendTo($('head'));
                    deferred.resolve();
                })
            );
        });
        return deferred.promise();
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Definitely makes sense, could you explain how to do that possibly?

Comment: @Chazt3n - OK, I've provided a coding example. (Haven't testing it, and it probably has a defect, but it gives you an idea of the approach).

Comment: So I'm still getting the same behavior. Could it be something to do with me using the attr function to loop through the result set?

Comment: Hi, it's great that you're helping with the promise tag! I'd like you to reconsider how you create those deferreds in your question - see if you think [this applies to your solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it) for example.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix this issue by mapping my promises to an array, and then handling them all at once using code from [This question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878887/how-do-you-work-with-an-array-of-jquery-deferreds)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        var links = $("html").find("link[rel=stylesheet]");
        var newLinks = [];

        if (!window.location.origin)
            window.location.origin = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;

        links.attr("href", function(i, value) {
            newLinks.push(window.location.origin + value);
        });

        var promises = $.map(newLinks, function(value) {
            return $.get(value, function(response) {
                $('<style />').text(response).appendTo($('head'));
            });
        });

        $.when.apply($, promises).then(function() {
            console.log(document.documentElement.outerHTML);
        });
    });

</script>
```