# API design: How can I combine result of two deferred jQuery objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, jquery-deferred

Suppose I able to get (`$.ajax`), process (`process_*`) and save (`store_* =`) data `A` and `B` independently and already have API:

```
var store_A;
function A() {
  $.ajax({url: "/getA"}).done(function(data) {
     store_A = process_A(data);
}); }

var store_B;
function B() {
  $.ajax({url: "/getB"}).done(function(data) {
     store_B = process_B(data);
}); }
```

I have a function `C()` that able to combine `store_A` and `store_B` into something:

```
var store_C;
function C() {
   store_C = process_C(store_A, store_B);
}
```

Suppose that `A()`, `B()` and `C()` is public API and all other stuff is internals and actually complex code (so for example I can't chain both `$.ajax` directly).

I want to refactor above code to new API by using [jQuery Deferred API](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) so I can request any case:

```
case1: after(A).do(C)
case1: after(B).do(C)
case2: afterParallelJobsFinished(A, B).do(C)
```

and be sure that `store_A` or `store_B` updated as requested and `store_C` updates only after update of one or both of A/B as requiested.

---

Imaging that we have webapp where user manage set of income and expenses.

On page loading we get incomes and expenses from different data-sources (that is `$.ajax`) **in parallel**, render view and store data (usually that are intermixed `process_*` / `store_* =`) and show `total = SUM(incomes) - SUM(expenses)` **when all data arrived**.

That is `case2`.

When user edit expenses and request partial page update we in `case1` because we need only load/render/store expanses to get correct `total = SUM(incomes) - SUM(expenses)`.

Comment: You can use $.when but you need to store promise in store_X.

Comment: From two independent `$.ajax()` I get two promises. How can I combine them? I want to preserve ability to run `A()` or `B()` or `C()` independently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$.when()` can take an arbitrary number of deferred objects. [It can even take a dynamic number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878887/how-do-you-work-with-an-array-of-jquery-deferreds) if you don't know how many calls you will make.

```
$.when(callA(), callB()).done(function() {
 // Do stuff here when both calls are done
});

function callA() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: ...,
    success: function() {
      // Do stuff here when callA is done
    }
  });
}

function callB() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: ...,
    success: function() {
      // Do stuff here when callB is done
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Nice! Can I use `return $.ajax().done(...)` syntax instead of `return $.ajax({success: ...})` ? Are they equivalent?

Comment: No, not the same. You don't want `done` being called when one of them is finished - only when they all finish.

Comment: Thanks. I think that my question mostly arose because of `done` vs `success` misunderstanding.

Comment: Very true. The docs don't make it at all clear how they work together. You can use `done` in replace of `success` in certain situations, but for the above use case, I recommend using both in the places as I have shown.

Comment: I would not use `done` but `then`. That way it is still returning a promise. like this: `return $.ajax().then(...)`. The `$.when()` will be fulfilled when each of the `then` functions from callA and callB are completed. Personally I think its a little ugly to mix `$.Deferred` logic with the success callback. "What happens first? What is actually returned? Do they both get passed the result? Does success chain?" All valid questions that can be avoided by sticking to just `$.Deferred`

Answer (score 2):

This is a revision of Matthew Herbst's answer sticking solely to Promise logic. This avoids unnecessary confusion from mixing Promise logic and the ajax `success:` callback.

```
$.when(callA(), callB()).done(function() {
    // Do stuff here when both .then()'s are complete
});

function callA() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: ...,
    }).then(function(result){
        // Do something when callA finishes
        return result;
    });
}

function callB() {
    return $.ajax({
        url: ...,
    }).then(function(result){
        // Do something when callB finishes
        return result;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Now when I become familiar with `jQuery.Deffered` API I want to add some more self expressed examples:

```
function callA() {
  return $.ajax({ url: ... })
    .done(function(data) { successA(data); })
    .fail(function(data) { failA(data); });
}

function callB() {
  var promise1 = $.ajax({ url: ... })
    .done(function(data) { succB_1(data); })
    .fail(function(data) { failB_1(data); });
  var promise2 = $.ajax({ url: ... })
    .done(function(data) { succB_2(data); })
    .fail(function(data) { failB_2(data); });
  return $.when(promise1, promise2)
    .done(function(data1, data2) { succCombined(data1, data2); })
    .fail(function(data1, data2) { failCombined(data1, data2); });
}

$.when(callA(), callB()).done(function() {
 // Do stuff here when both calls are done
});
```

Note that inside `callA`/`callB` I use `data`/`data1`/`data2` because I know internal API agreement. In last lines I don't expect that `callA`/`callB` return something sensible. But if I add public API to `callA`/`callB` I can use:

```
$.when(callA(), callB()).done(function(resultA, resultB) {
 // Do stuff here when both calls are done
});
```