# Deferred and Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

Reading a JSON-Service like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'activeIDs',
  success : function(data){ // data = [14,15]
    var tableRows = [];
    for (var dataIndex=0; dataIndex < data.length; dataIndex++) {
      var isLast = dataIndex == (data.length - 1);
      $.ajax({
        url: 'info?id=' + data[dataIndex],
        success: function(data2) { // "foo", "bar"
          tableRows.push(data2.name);
          if (isLast) {
            alert(tableRows.length);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

First network-trace is:

1. activeIDs = `[14,15]`
2. info?id=14 (takes 2 seconds) = `"foo"`
3. info?id=15 (takes 4 seconds) = `"bar"`

In this case the alert gives "2".

Seconds network-trace is different:

1. activeIDs = `[14,15]`;
2. info?id=14 (takes 20 seconds) = `"foo"` (now takes very long)
3. info?id=15 (takes 1 second) = `"bar"`

In this case the alert gives `1` after one second, this is **bad!!!**

### Question:

How to use $.Deferred instead of `isLast`?

Comment: I guess you have no guarantee that last request will be finished last.

Comment: Thats true, only `$.Deferred` may know when the last request has been finished AFAIK. But how to use `$.Deferred`?

Comment: I could use  `if (data.length == entries.length) {` but i realy like to have a solution using `$.Deferred`.

Comment: why do you need multiple ajax calls?

Comment: @madalinivascu because the result of some calls are already cached in the browser, others may not!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878887/how-do-you-work-with-an-array-of-jquery-deferreds

Comment: I have edited my answer based on jQuery `when` since localStorage was out of the question. @PeterRader

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to wait for all requests to finish before `alert`ing.

```
$.ajax({
  url:'activeIDs',
  success : function(data){ // data = [14,15]
    var tableRows = [];
    var requests = [];
    for (var dataIndex=0; dataIndex < data.length; dataIndex++) {
      var isLast = dataIndex == data.length;

      var request = $.ajax({
        url: 'info?id=' + data[dataIndex]
      }).done(function(data2) { // "foo", "bar"
        tableRows.push(data2.name);
      });

      requests.push(request);
    }

    // wait for all requests to finish here
    $.when(requests).then(function(){
      // all success functions have been called and updated things appropriately
      alert(tableRows.length);
    }
  }
});
```

This assumes that all requests succeed. <strike>It also looks like there are a few typos</strike>

- Where does `tableRows` get updated?
- Where is `entries` defined?

**Edit**
Now using promise style success handler. Should push the result in to `tableRows` before calling the `$.when().then` callback

Comment: This is cool, `$.when` returns a `Promise` and accepts `Defferred`s as arguments, so I think it's exactly what OP wants.

Comment: Do i need the `requests`-Array?

Comment: Yes, you need to pass all the Deferreds in to `$.when()`

Comment: Turns out was not correct, `then` triggering before join the success-handler. How to reproduce: Insert an `alert('wait');` before the `tableRows.push(data2.name);`. You will become three alerts: "wait", "wait" and "**0**"

Comment: Ahh, should probably use promise style from `$.ajax` rather than the success callback to allow predictable behaviour... Answer updated. Try not to use the `success` and `error` callbacks. Better to use the Deferred/Promise style

Comment: Docu sais nothing about .ajax in this case, but sais something about a "notify" to complete Deferreds.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want $.Deferred ? Your $.ajax calls are returning a promise, so, you can use it:

```
var promisesArray = [];
for (var dataIndex=0; dataIndex < data.length; dataIndex++) {
  promisesArray.push($.ajax({...}));
}
 $.when.apply($, promisesArray).then(...);
```

(inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5627284/pass-in-an-array-of-deferreds-to-when) answer)

You can use deferreds by taking this solution and passing it to a deferred if you want, but it's not neccesary:

```
var x = $.Deferred(function(defer){  
    var promisesArray = [];
    for (var dataIndex=0; dataIndex < data.length; dataIndex++) {
      promisesArray.push($.ajax({...}));
    }
     $.when.apply($, promisesArray).done(function(data) { defer.resolve(data); });
});
return x.promise();
```

(Not tested, I'm sorry)