# What is the best pattern for checking completion of jquery promises in JSON objects?

Tags: jquery, json, promise, getjson

I have a list of numbers and I want to create an array of JSON objects with created from querying the numbers from an api. For example, if the numbers are

```
numbers = [1, 4];
```

Then I want a JSON object created like such:

```
[{
  number: 1,
  data: $.getJSON('/api/numbers/1')
},
{
  number: 4,
  data: $.getJSON('/api/numbers/4')
}]
```

The simplest way I would think would be to map the list of numbers to a corresponding JSON object:

```
numbers_data = numbers.map(n => {number: n, data: $.getJSON('/api/numbers'+ n)})
```

However, once I have the `numbers_data` with the embedded `$.getJSON` promises, I'm not sure how to tell when all the api calls have completed. Is there a pattern that would let me tell when the variable `numbers_data` is fully resolved so that I can do something with it?

Comment: You could `$.when` to "combine" the promises into one and then attach a callback to know when everything is done.

Comment: In the end, do you want your object to contain the promise or the JSON data returned from the AJAX call?]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you work with an array of jQuery Deferreds?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4878887/1048572)?

Comment: I want the object to contain the data returned. Yea, here is what I had using `$.when` but I felt that it was too complicated:
    
    promises = numbers.map(function(n){
 return ($.getJSON('numbers/'+n));
    })

    datasets = numbers.map(function(n){
 return {number: n, data: null};
    });

    $.when(promises).then(data) {
 for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
  datasets[i]["data"] = data[i];
 }
    }

Comment: If jqueries promises are 'thenable' you can use ES6 Promise.all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.when` to basically "combine" the promises into one.  You can then attach a `.done()` handler to the output of `$.when` and know once *all* your AJAX calls are done.  You can then access all the returned JSON data and use it/build your object as needed.

Something like this:

```
var promises = [],
    numbers_data = numbers.map(number => {
        var data = $.getJSON('/api/numbers'+number);

        promises.push(data);
        return {number, data};
    });

// This will let you know once *all* promises are resolved.
$.when.apply($, promises).done(() => {
    // Each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]
    for(var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++){
        numbers_data[i].data = arguments[i][0];
    }
});
```

Comment: That's the solution I had originally, I was just wondering if there was a more functional way to do it. Although ultimately this might end up being the simplest solution anyway.

Comment: @Daniel _"I was just wondering if there was a more functional way to do it"_ What do you mean by "more functional"?

Comment: Cleaner nowadays to replace $.when.apply() with Promise.all(). Results in `then()` is true array of only the response data