# How to fix async behavior for a getJSON call in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, foreach, getjson

I am working on a small project where I want to check the `status` of a streaming `channel` using an API and display that channels status and information if the status is `online`

Here's what I'm thinking

```
const channelNames = ['channel1', 'channel2'];
var channels = [];

function Channel(name, status) {
    this.name = name;
    this.status = status;
}

//build the channels array of Channels
for(var name in channelNames) {
    channels.push(new Channel(channelNames[name], null));
}

channels.forEach(function(channel) {

    // call the API to get the status
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        // in here update the status to 'online' or 'offline' depending on 
        // the response from the API
    });

    //Add additional properties to the object if the status is now 'online'
    if(channel.status === 'online') {
        $.getJSON(differentUrl, function(data) {
            // in here add more properties to the object depending on the
            // response from the API
        });
    }
});
```

How can I make these async calls synchronous so that I can build the `Channel` objects in the `channels` array based on the responses of API calls? After I build the `channels` array I'm going to iterate through them to great new HTML elements to display their properties.

Comment: Inside `.forEach()` you update the `status` async but trying to access it sync. No good..!

Comment: this old so question might be of help to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878887/how-do-you-work-with-an-array-of-jquery-deferreds

Comment: As a side note do not use for in to iterate over Arrays. Use foreach in this scenario instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bit is to use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all). Here's a pseudo code (not a working one - just a sketch for you to implement) you can use

```
let channelNames = [a lot of ids here];
let promises = [];

while (channelNames.length > 0) {
    promises.push($getJSON(url).then(function() {}))
}

Promise.all(promises)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will give this a shot. What about the second $.getJSON call i need to do once I find out if the channel is 'online' or 'offline'? This call has a different endpoint (so different url). Should i put it in the function inside of the .then?

Comment: That should be inside `.then()` as you want to update behavior from first response