# Typescript - Wait for promise resolve before function return

Tags: typescript, asynchronous

*Updated with working solution*

I start with a function that grabs information from all rows selected in a table and pushes that information into a stack for later processing.

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.selectedItems().length; i++) {
    var row = this.selectedItems()[i];
    let info = this.createFileReqInfo(row.Number(), FileRequestType.AssociatedDoc);
    fileReqInfo.push(info);
}
```

**My Problem**: The `createFileReqInfo` function returns before the asynchronous API call can return a value, so I'm not getting the right value for userCanView in the return object.

```
createFileReqInfo = (reportId: number, fileRequestType: FileRequestType) : any => {
    let fileReq = new FileRequest(reportId, fileRequestType);
    var uCanView = false;
    this.reportModel.getReportSecurity(reportId).done((result) => {
        uCanView = result.CanViewReport;
        var info: {
            fileRequest: FileRequest,
            userCanView: boolean
        } = {
            fileRequest: fileReq,
            userCanView: uCanView
        }
        return info;        
    });
}
```

The compiler won't let me use `await` here. Any ideas on how to get the function to block until the API call returns?

---

**Solution**

My problem here is that there were a few levels of function calls here that I had to rework to create and resolve promises. The function that calls the API resembles something in the suggested solutions

```
createFileReqInfo = (reportId: number, fileRequestType: FileRequestType) : JQueryPromise<any> => {
    let fileReq = new FileRequest(reportId, fileRequestType);
    var uCanView = false;

    var info: {
        fileRequest: FileRequest,
        userCanView: boolean
    } = {
        fileRequest: fileReq,
        userCanView: uCanView
    }

    let dfd: JQueryDeferred<any> = $.Deferred();

    this.reportModel.getReportSecurity(reportId).done((result) => {
        uCanView = result.CanViewReport;
        info.userCanView = uCanView;
        dfd.resolve(info);
    });

    return dfd;
}
```

This now returns a promise. The problem I had is with the function that calls this one because it iterates through a list of selected items and queues up various reports to download, but only the ones that exist in that particular selection. Had to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878887/how-do-you-work-with-an-array-of-jquery-deferreds) answer to figure out a way to wait for all the promises to resolve before continuing.

```
getFileReqsFromSelectedItems = (view1: boolean, view2: boolean, view3: boolean): JQueryPromise<any> => {
    var fileReqInfo: {
        fileRequest: FileRequest,
        userCanView: boolean
    }[] = [];

    let dfd: JQueryDeferred<any> = $.Deferred();

    let promise: JQueryPromise<any>;
    let promiseArray: JQueryPromise<any>[] = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < this.selectedItems().length; i++) {
        var row = this.selectedItems()[i];

        if( view1 && row.HasView1() ) {
            promise = this.createFileReqInfo(row.Number(), FileRequestType.AssociatedDoc1);
            promiseArray.push(promise);
        }
        if( view2 && row.HasView2() ) {
            promise = this.createFileReqInfo(row.Number(), FileRequestType.AssociatedDoc2);
            promiseArray.push(promise);
        }
        if( view3 && row.HasView3() ) {
            promise = this.createFileReqInfo(row.Number(), FileRequestType.AssociatedDoc3);
            promiseArray.push(promise);
        }
    }

    $.when.apply($, promiseArray).done(function() {
        var promises = arguments;
        for (var j = 0; j < promises.length; j++)
        {
            fileReqInfo.push(promises[j]);
        }
        dfd.resolve(fileReqInfo);
    });

    return dfd;
}
```

After that, it was easy to take the array of returned values and pass it to the download function.

```
downloadReports = () => {
    this.getFileReqsFromSelectedItems(this.view1Check(), this.view2Check(), this.view3Check()).then((fileReqsDetails) => { 
        this.downloadTrialFiles(fileReqsDetails);
    });
}
```

Whew!

Comment: Out of curiosity - can you show how you were trying to use `async`/`await` and what the compiler error is?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For APIs that don't support promises, you can use `new Promise` to create a promise yourself, call `resolve` with the result of the async call, then you can use async/await syntax when calling it. [More info on promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
interface ReportSecurityInfo {
    fileRequest: FileRequest
    userCanView: boolean
}

createFileReqInfo = (reportId: number, fileRequestType: FileRequestType): Promise<any> => {
    let fileReq = new FileRequest(reportId, fileRequestType);
    var uCanView = false;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.reportModel.getReportSecurity(reportId).done((result) => {
            uCanView = result.CanViewReport;
            var info: ReportSecurityInfo = {
                fileRequest: fileReq,
                userCanView: uCanView
            }
            resolve(info)
        });
    })
}

// somewhere else...
const info = await this.createFileReqInfo()
```

I also went ahead and split out the type of `info` as its own interface for readability.

Comment: Isn't this just pushing the same problem up the stack? I can't use `await` without defining the function it appears in as `async`, which will require another promise.

Comment: If one function you're using is asynchronous, then all of its callers have to be, and the callers of those callers, and so on. This is just how async in JS works.

Comment: This put me down the right path to a full answer, but, boy did I have to work on it. I will update the original question with my eventual solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can return promise from createFileReqInfo , then wait until it resolves

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.selectedItems().length; i++) {
    var row = this.selectedItems()[i];
    let info = await this.createFileReqInfo(row.Number(), FileRequestType.AssociatedDoc);
    fileReqInfo.push(info);
}
```

Or

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.selectedItems().length; i++) {
    var row = this.selectedItems()[i];
    this.createFileReqInfo(row.Number(), FileRequestType.AssociatedDoc)
       .then(info => {
               fileReqInfo.push(info);
            });

}
```

Where `createFileReqInfo` is defined as:

```
createFileReqInfo = (reportId: number, fileRequestType: FileRequestType) : Promise<any> => {
  return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
    let fileReq = new FileRequest(reportId, fileRequestType);
    var uCanView = false;
    this.reportModel.getReportSecurity(reportId).done((result) => {
        uCanView = result.CanViewReport;
        var info: {
            fileRequest: FileRequest,
            userCanView: boolean
        } = {
            fileRequest: fileReq,
            userCanView: uCanView
        }
        resolve(info);        
    });
    }
}
```