# Conjuring JQuery Deferred with monadic incantations

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, monads, jquery-deferred

Inspired by [this](http://blog.jcoglan.com/2011/03/11/promises-are-the-monad-of-asynchronous-programming/) (excellent) discussion of using Promises in javascript, I'm trying to work out how I could use Deferred to chain together async and non-async functions, to avoid paying the callback tax when using my '[Global storage](http://jsfiddle.net/Benjol/XNbXF/)' code.

I've got a few questions related to this, but I'll ask them together here, because the context is the same.

One thing I can't work out is how I can make a deferred out of something that isn't asynchronous - that is, how do I take a value, wrap it in a promise, and return it directly? (`a -> M<a>`)

Also, how can I take an asynchronous function and wrap it so that it returns its result directly, but wrapped in a promise? (`(a -> b) -> (a -> M<b>)`)

Last question, for monadic freaks - is there a standard name for this function? `[a] -> (a -> M<b>) -> M<[b]>`

Comment: For anyone who's landed here trying to work out how to 'chain' deferred objects, I've come up with (what seems to me like) an elegant solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Benjol/DjrRD/

Answer (score 5):

Wrapping a value into a promise is as simple as using $.when:

```
var promise = $.when( value );
```

Also, as of jQuery 1.6, you have a very simple chaining method (pipe):

```
var chained = functionThatReturnsAPromise().pipe(function( resolveValue ) {
        return functionThatReturnsAnotherPromise( resolveValue );
    });

chained.done(function() {
    // Both asynchronous operations done in sequence
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Very nice, thanks. As it happens, I was tailoring it for here, where they haven't upgraded to 1.6 yet (AFAIK), but the $.when is handy.

Comment: For anyone that's curious, `$.when(value)` is shorthand for `$.Deferred().resolve(value).promise()`

Answer (score 1):

I *think* the way that you'd turn a value into a Promise is to just "pre-succeed" the Deferred:

```
function v2p(value) {
  var rv = $.Deferred();
  rv.resolveWith(null, [value]);
  return rv.promise();
}
```

Now passing a function to ".done()" will result in the function being immediately called with the value.

```
v2p("hello").done(function(value) { alert(value); });
```

would immediately alert "hello".

Comment: That's a great start, thanks! I edited your answer to get it to run, hope it hasn't denatured what you meant.

Comment: Oh yes, right; sorry about that.  I have only barely played with that Deferred stuff so far, but it seems really cool :-)

Answer (score 1):

Helped along by @Pointy, implementing 'lift' becomes trivial:

```
function unit(value) {
  var rv = $.Deferred();
  rv.resolveWith(null, [value]);
  return rv.promise();
}
function lift(fn) {
  return function(x) {
    return unit(fn(x));
  };
}
lift(alert)("hello");

function bind(fn) {
   return function(x) {
     return x.done(function(y) { return fn(y); });
   }
}

function compose(f, g) { return function(x) { g(f(x)); } };
function twice(x) { return 2 * x; }
var alert2 = compose(bind(lift(twice)), bind(lift(alert)));

alert2(unit(4)); //error at the end because alert doesn't return any values
```

Now I just have to work out how to implement `[a] -> (a -> M<b>) -> M<[b]>`, and what to call it!

**EDIT**, I ended up implementing `(a -> M<b>) -> ([a] -> M<[b]>)` instead, it looks like this:

```
function listBind(fn) {
    return function(a) {        
      var Mb = $.Deferred();
      var b = [], pending = a.length;
      var callback = function(i,val) {
         b[i] = val;
         if(--pending == 0) Mb.resolve(b);
      };
      for(var i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; i++) {
          (function(closure) { //ugly, but have to use closure to 'copy' i
             fn(a[closure]).done(function(val) { callback(closure, val); })
          })(i);
      }
      return Mb.promise();
    };
}
```

So, given a function which gets one deferred item, this function listBind returns a new function which accepts an array of values, and uses them to return another list of values inside a deferred item.