# How to implement an ajax request queue using jQuery

Tags: ajax, jquery, ajax-request

What is the best way to implement an Ajax request queue using jQuery? Specifically, I want to accomplish the following:

- A user triggers any number of Ajax requests within a web page, which need to be queued up and submitted sequentially.
- The web page needs to receive responses from the server and adjust itself accordingly.
- Finally, if an error occurs (connection lost, server failed to respond, etc.), I want jQuery to invoke a JavaScript function.

I'm struggling with the last requirement in particular, as the error handling mechanism in jQuery's Ajax functions is not very intuitive. Are there any examples/tutorials that could help me with this task?

Thanks!

Comment: You might like this: http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a few buffers like this. Some examples can be found [simple task Buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869609/how-can-jquery-deferred-be-used) and [deferred item queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505828/how-do-you-attach-callbacks-to-the-deferred-object-that-is-attached-to-a-deferred).

As for error handling you can always use [`.ajaxError`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/)

Comment: Thanks, these look promising!

Comment: @Jen if you use node on the server, think about using socket.io or now ;)

Answer (score 1):

jQuery ajax has an error attribute where you can attach a function and the method will only fire if an error occurs. See the below example:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "url",
            dataType:"json",
            data:{},
            success:function(data){                    
                alert("Succeed!");
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }    
        });
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: Thanks! I've tried these error handlers before, but found their behavior quite unpredictable. I would get a *success* indication even if the connection was lost...