# Pass JSON object up the tree

Tags: jquery, json, variables

I have a JSON object that is returned inside a function (see below) and that in turn is inside a parent function and then a global function. There is a further child function within that global function that needs access to the JSON to parse the records.

I have left out some things that are not really part of the problem but hopefully included enough to explain the problem I have! You can see that

```
MyFunc.prototype.CreateMine = function(){
//do some work...
    submit: function(e,v,m,f){
        var xhr = new jsonRequest()
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            var jsonText = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); //jsonText now contains my data
        };
    }
//need to access jsonText...
    }
}
```

Let me know if the example of not complete enough, thanks in advance Chris

Comment: Why not just pass this `jsonText` variable _value_ to some external function - as a param? I mean something as simple as `someExternalFunc(jsonText);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you should learn more about how [scopes in JavaScript](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/01/what-you-need-to-know-about-javascript-scope/) work. To put it simple, all variables created in the outer functions are available in the inner ones. So you just have to declare your `jsonText` in one of the "upper" functions.

Notice the absence of `var` in `submit`: this way it will try to find `jsonText` variable upper in the scope tree:

```
MyFunc.prototype.CreateMine = function(){
    var jsonText
    //do some work...
    submit: function(e,v,m,f){
        var xhr = new jsonRequest()
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            jsonText = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText); //jsonText now contains my data
        };
    }
    jsonText // available
    }
}
```

However, in your case a [callback](http://www.phpied.com/async-javascript-callbacks/) or a [deferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869609/how-can-jquery-deferred-be-used) would be better, because in `submit` `jsonText` is changed asynchronously, so you can't access it right after invoking `submit`.

```
function myCallback(myData) {
    // do smt with your data
}
MyFunc.prototype.CreateMine = function(){
    //do some work...
    submit: function(e,v,m,f){
        var xhr = new jsonRequest()
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){
            var jsonText = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            myCallback(jsonText)
        };
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response...I appreciate the comments. The first method did not work for me, but the second seems to, in that I can pass the contents of jsonText to the myCallback function, but I still cannot get that in the MyFunc function where I need it. Thanks for any further help!

Comment: oh, and in my example, the data in myCallback function is available as myData, not as jsonText

Comment: I can email it...it is quite big and relies on other objects.

Comment: well... so, do you have myData available inside myCallback function?