# Modifying JSONP results before success callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsonp, jquery-deferred

I'd like to load some JSON data from an external service.  However, it provides

```
{ foo: ..., bar: ..., useful: {...} }
```

and what I really care about is in the "useful" part.  I need to pass just that part to the `success` callback.

I'm trying to use `Deferred` to load from multiple data sources at once -- something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869609/how-can-jquery-deferred-be-used#4874732).  I'd like to retrieve the data, "massage" the result, and have just the "useful" part in the example above actually passed to the `then` callback.  My understanding is that when you pass a `Deferred` to `when()`, the data goes directly to the callback passed to `then()`, so I need to hook into the process before it gets there.

I tried `dataFilter` but for JSONP that's [not possible](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/1-5-ajax-datafilter-not-working).  Is there any other way to intercept these results?  I can add some checks to my `then()` callback to handle cached data differently from the "fresh" results, but that sort of loses the magic of `Deferred` in the first place.

To clarify, this doesn't work:

```
$.when($.ajax({
  url: "host/service",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  dataFilter: function(data, type){
    return data.useful; // throws, data === undefined
  }
})).then(function(usefulStuff){ ... });
```

Comment: Please post some code that you have tried...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `.pipe()` to process the data and create a new Deferred:

```
$.getJSON(...).pipe(function(results) {
    return ...;
})
```