# Mocking/Intercepting JSONP requests coming from DOM script injection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, sinon

I am currently setting up tests that utilize OpenLayers and I would like to be able to mock requests to services like Bing Maps in Karma unit tests. I've tried to use Sinon to mock XHR requests but realized it is [generating these requests by dynamically creating and injecting a `script` tag into the DOM `head` and binding the JSONP response](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers/Layer/Bing.js#L174).

I am using PhantomJS on TravisCI and Chrome locally to test and I am trying to work out how provide my own JSONP response in place of the request coming from injecting this tag into the `head` element. This will be to reduce on API requests, speed up testing and avoid potential API/network issues occurring during unit tests.

Currently I've tried SinonJS using the following setup.

```
server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
server.respondWith('GET', bingRequestUrl,
    [200, {"Content-Type": "application/x-javascript; charset=utf-8"},
        bingFakeResponse
]);

$scope.$digest();
$timeout.flush();
server.restore();
```

The idea being that I am only mocking requests during the time they will be processed and then restoring normal functionality.

Is there are way to achieve what I need using Sinon or does it only mock XHR requests and not requests coming from DOM manipulation shown in this example.

Comment: Is it not possible to use https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend to mock the requests?

Comment: @Praval'Shaun'Tirubeni I tried that but still had problems. I think `$httpBackend` is only mocking requests that use `$http`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modifying JSONP results before success callback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649399/modifying-jsonp-results-before-success-callback)