# jquery deferred for async methods

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I have a function that internally makes ajax call and has success and failure callback method.

```
function dothis() {
    object.getMyData(x,y,successCallback,failureCallback);
}
```

the function returns immediately since getMyData is an async one . Now i want the function dothis to wait until successCallback or failureCallback is executed . How to do it using deferred ?

Answer (score 1):

`ajax` already returns a deferred, so you could just use that.  Can you change `getMyData` to return the deferred that `ajax` returns?

```
function getMyData() {
    return ajax({
        // ajax params
    });
}

function dothis() {
    // return deferred which comes from ajax
    return object.getMyData(x,y,successCallback,failureCallback); 
}

dothis().done(function(){
    // do something on success
}).fail(function(){
    // do something on failure
});
```

If you can't change `getMyData` to return the deferred, you can do this:

```
function dothis() {
    var dfd = $.Deferred();
    object.getMyData(x,y,function(){
        dfd.resolve(); // success
    },function(){
        dfd.reject();  // fail
    });
    return dfd.promise(); 
}

dothis().done(function(){
    // do something on success
}).fail(function(){
    // do something on failure
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you don't need an asynchronous call.

Did you try to do a sync call and then perform the success/failure function ? Please clarify.

Thanks,

@leo

Sync Call Example>

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: remote_url,
        async: false,
        success : function(data) {
            remote = data;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I preferr you to use $.when and $.then combination of jquery deferred.

You can visit [this](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/)

You can also found relative answer in [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869609/how-can-jquery-deferred-be-used) too.