# jquery firing actions after document ready

Tags: jquery

I need to perform this step:-

1. When document is ready,
2. do function A,
3. After function A is completed,
4. perform function B, C, D

Though not exactly the answer, the following way works:-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    function_a();
    setTimeout(function(){
        function_b(); 
        function_c();
        function_d();
    }, 100);
});
</script>
```

Surely, I cannot always depend on time delay! However, the following way is not working:-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    function_a();
}).complete(function(){
    function_b(); 
    function_c();
    function_d();
});
</script>
```

How can the second way be improved?

Comment: Are your functions asynchronous ? Then they certainly accept a callback as paremeter, don't they ?

Comment: the functions must be worked out step by step, otherwise the final effect will be incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function_a();
    function_b(); 
    function_c();
    function_d();

});
```

Will do the same if functions are synchronous.
For Asynchronus functions use callbacks.
This might help : [How should I call 3 functions in order to execute them one after the other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187968/how-should-i-call-3-functions-in-order-to-execute-them-one-after-the-other)

Comment: will not work if function function_a() has asynchronous actions

Comment: @Cris: Was about to mention it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
function_a();

function function_a()
{
 ........
 function_b();
}

function function_b()
{
 ........
 function_c();
}

function function_c()
{
  ........
 function_d();
}
```

Comment: only if all are synchronous.

Answer (score 1):

You could just do with below if `function_a` works synchronous.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function_a();
    function_b(); 
    function_c();
    function_d();
});
```

But if it works asynchronous, then `function_a` should provide a parameter for complete callback:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function_a(function(){
      function_b(); 
      function_c();
      function_d();
    });
});
```

Comment: **+1** and it's good idea to write `function_a` and how it accept a callback for making this answer better `;)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to functions follow the that sequence you have to impelled [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/). Read about jQuery `.when()`, `.then()`. jQuery is made for this.

[How can jQuery deferred be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869609/how-can-jquery-deferred-be-used)

http://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/examples/

## or

```
function_a();
function_b(); 
function_c();
function_d();
```

Above method is also correct. But this method won't work if `function_a()` has asynchronous functions.