# Unwinding promises and their handlers

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, scripting

I want to launch a sequence of tasks and I need they execute in order. When a button (#submitButton) is clicked on the entire process is launched (startAll function), so I implement an architecture like this:

```
function startAll()
{
   var startDeferred, highPriorityTasksDeferred, lowPriorityTasksDeferred, finalizeDeferred;

   startDeferred = $.Deferred;

   **highPriorityTasksDeferred= startDeferred.then(initialize).done(initiate); <-- ERROR HERE**

   lowPriorityTasksDeferred= highPriorityTasksDeferred.then(function () {
            console.log('Processing HIGH priority tasks...');
            return highPriorityTasks;
   })
   .done(function () {
            console.log('HIGH priority taks processed.');
   });

   finalizeDeferred= lowPriorityTasksDeferred.then(function () {
            console.log('Processing LOW priority tasks...');
            return lowPriorityTasks;
   })
   .done(function () {
            console.log('LOW priority taks processed.');
   });

   finalizeDeferred.then(finalize).done(terminate);

   // Starts all
   startDeferred.resolve();
}

function initialize() {
    // Things to be initialized just before starting process
    console.log('</br>Initiating process...');

    // Stuff

    return;
}

function initiate() {
    // Once initialized, do simple things
    setButtonDisabled(true);

    console.log('Process started at ' + $.now()+ '<br/>');

    return;
}

function finalize() {
    // Things to be done just before ending process
    // Free resources, etc.
    console.log('<br/>Finishing process...');

    // Stuff

    return;
}

function terminate() {
    // Things to be done once finished is done.
    // Simple things such as those related to UI.
    setButtonDisabled(false);

    console.log('<br/>Process terminated at ' + $.now());

    return;
}

function setButtonDisabled(status) {
    $('#submitButton').prop("disabled", status);
}
```

high/lowPriorityTasks methods have a structure like this:

```
function high/lowPriorityTasks() {

    getTasks().then(function (response) {

       // stuff

    }).then(function () {

       // stuff 

    }).fail(function (err) {

       // stuff
    });
}
```

**Console Output** for this should be:

```
Initiating process...
Process started at XXX

Processing HIGH priority tasks...
HIGH priority taks processed.

Processing LOW priority tasks...
LOW priority taks processed.

Finishing process...
Process terminated at XXX
```

**Important notes**:

1. Functions initialize, initiate, finalize and terminate, their last command is return; 
   but I am not sure if it is correct.
2. I am using jQuery 1.10.2 and asp.net MVC 4

**Observed issues**:

1. When executing it, a runtime error is raised saying that the object
   does not accept the property or method 'then' at line bolded:

   highPriorityTasksDeferred= startDeferred.then(initialize).done(initiate);

**First attempt**:

As kenneth has said, brackets after $.Deferred were missed so by adding them $.Deferred() the process is executed but some issues appears: It seems like, the high/lowPriorityTasks functions are not executed as in the console is displayed:

```
Initiating process...
Process started at XXX


Finishing process...

Process terminated at XXX
```

Any ideas? Also i would like to know if the return; in the functions initialize, initiate, finalize and terminate is the best way to do it or there is another best option.

**Second attempt**:

Some brackets were missed for highPriorityTasks and lowPriorityTasks when called so now they are executed correctly but the problem is that they are not done in order....

Answer (score 1):

You're missing brackets after the `$.Deferred`. At the moment it's returning the deferred-function not a Deferred-object.

Change it to the following and it should work:

```
startDeferred = $.Deferred();
```

Comment: You are right, brackets after $.Deferred were missed. By adding them now process starts but new issues have appeared, see my last updated post in "first attempt".

Comment: You're never resolving the startDeffered promise. That's the reason why nothing in the chain is called. From what I can see you're doing everything synchronous (I suppose you posted a simplification). it makes it hard to see what you're trying to do though.

Comment: yes, high/low priority tasks also uses $.Deferred to do some things in order, and in the most outer, i do this, another $.Deferred that does the tasks (high/low) in order. If i call high/lowPriorityTasks alone, it works, but what I want now it the chaninng to work in this sequence: initialize, initiate, highPriorityTasks, lowPriorityTasks, finalize and then terminate as shown in the output console provided in the post.I have remove the return from initialize,initiate,finalize and terminate methods and also some brackets when calling functions highPriorityTasks and lowPriorityTasks were missed.

Comment: startDeferred promise is resolved, see line of code startDeferred.resolve() the problem was that some brackets were missed from method commented in previous post. Now it works, but the only problem is that they are not called in sequence....

Comment: see here more in details: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/unwinding-promises-and-their-handlers-asp-net-mvc-and-jquery