# How to make Jquery $.each loop wait for operation to complete before iterating?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that has a $.each to loop over keys of an object and do stuff. within this loop i am calling a function which in turns makes a call to the server to get some data and does things with it in a callback. these calls are asynchronous so the $.each does not wait for the data to come and the callback to do what its supposed to and keeps iterating. How do i make the $.each loop wait till i complete my operation and then continue.

```
$.each(messages,function(key) {  
//do something 
if(some Condition) {
getfromserver(token,myCallback); }
//do something 
});




function myCallback(data)
 {
   //do something with data
 }
```

Comment: Well you are better off not using each...

Comment: @epascarello will using "for" solve this problem?

Comment: `each` is not built for what you want, but the functions mentioned on the question I linked as a duplicate all do what you need.  And, when we get into the next version of Javascript, [such mechanisms will be a native part of the language](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/)

Comment: @ScottMermelstein I don't know if I'd agree with that duplicate. The solution proposed there is not relevant for server IO.

Comment: @Peter That was sloppy of me.  You're right, the duplicate I posted didn't help enough.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869609/how-can-jquery-deferred-be-used is more of what I was thinking of.  You want a deferral mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this instead of `$.each`, I call it callback loop:

```
iterate(messages, 0);

function iterate(arr, i) {
    if(i==arr.length) return;
    var message = arr[i];
    //you might want to create your token based on current message
    var token = "...";

    if(/*some Condition*/){
        getfromserver(token, function (data) {
            myCallback(data);
            iterate(arr, i++);
        });
    }
    //use this else if you want to do something like 'continue'
    //and don't use it if it kinda 'break'
    else iterate(arr, i++);
}

function myCallback(data) {
    //do something with data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't with a simple iteration. Instead you should do this:

```
function unqueue() {
  if (!messages.length)
    return;
  var key =  messages.pop();
  // do something
  getfromserver(token, myCallback);
  //do something
}

function myCallback(data) {
  //do something with data

  // Repeat it until messages is not empty
  unqueue();
}

unqueue();
```

Comment: -1 Doesn't solve the problem asked by OP. This doesn't wait for the server IO to complete before requesting the next.

Comment: I thought the callback was located the line after getfromserver. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea of adding the loop into your callback

```
var messages = {foo:"1","bar":2,"asdf":3}; 
var keys = $.map(messages, function(val, key) { return key});

function makeCall() {
   if(!keys.length) return;
   var next = keys.shift();
   var token = messages[next];
   getfromserver(token,myCallback);
}

function myCallback(data)
 {
   //do something with data
   makeCall();
 }
```

There are tons of ways of building up a queue of calls.

Answer (score 0):

This is in coffeescript, but I think it does what you need. You keep throwing execution forward into a function, much like in nodejs:

```
processMessages = (messages, callback, args) ->
    # End it by returning the callback result when messages are done
    return callback() unless messages.length

    # Shift the first message off the list
    message = messages.shift()

    # Send it to the server for something to do
    $.ajax
        url: '/echo/json/'
        method: 'POST'
        data:
            json: JSON.stringify({ message: message, args: args })
        dataType: 'json'
        success:(data) ->
            # Respond to the server's response
            console.log 'Got ' + data.message

            # Process the remaining messages
            processMessages messages, callback, args

finished = ->
    console.log 'all done here'

processMessages ['hi', 'bob'], finished, 'yo'
```

Coffeescript: http://jsfiddle.net/datashaman/22gDa/3/

Javascript fork: http://jsfiddle.net/datashaman/3zdQ8/1/