# Get class of dynamically created div - jQuery

Tags: jquery, dynamic, get, click

Alright I have this :

```
$('.myKnownClass').click(function() {

            $('.menu').addClass('testingClass');

 });
```

When I click on the .myKnownClass, another script adds a div.menu, but it doesn't create it instantly (like 0.4 seconds, depends on the server).

Is there any way, within the "click", to wait till a div.menu is present on the body ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can use `setTimeout` to delay your script, but it would be vey unreliable. Does the other script not provide you any events when it has completed?

Comment: how you are creating your `div.menu`

Comment: Simple rule with AJAX: anything that depends on the response must be done in the callback function. So move the `addClass` code there.

Comment: No, I don't have access to this script, that is why I am asking this.

Comment: so simply use `setInterval()`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$('.myKnownClass').click(function() {

            var interval = setInterval(function(){
                   if($(".menu").length){
                          $('.menu').addClass('testingClass');
                          clearInterval(interval);
                   }
            },200);

 });
```

Comment: Why would you want this to happen every 200ms? I think you want `setTimeout`, but even that is a flawed solution as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do something with jQuerys Deferreds.
I don't really know how to use it, but maybe you can do something with it.

[How can jQuery deferred be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869609/how-can-jquery-deferred-be-used)