# Javascript start processing next event only then first finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

My JS event looks like:

```
        $(document).on('change', 'input[name="' + ID +'[]"]', function() {
            upload($(this));
        });
```

So multiple fields can invoke this event, how I can call

```
upload($(this));
```

only then if previous event is finished ?

Comment: what do you mean by event is finished ?

Comment: I mean that when `upload();` is executed by first event only then allow 2

Comment: You should use a queue system to push each event as they are called. Take a look at the `Async` library: https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: it depends on what does the `upload` function do ? It is not a `async` function then you don't have to do any changes it will work as u expected

Comment: @murli2308 idea is not allow execute multiple `upload();` on same time

Comment: See: [How can jQuery deferred be used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869609/how-can-jquery-deferred-be-used?lq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup a `queue` management system, using the [`Async`](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue) library for example, with something like:

```
var q = async.queue(function (element, callback) {
    // calling the upload task with the element arguments
    upload(element)
    // calling next task
    callback();
}, 1); // we limit the task to 1 at a time

$(document).on('change', 'input[name="' + ID +'[]"]', function() {
    // enqueing the task with $(this) as argument
    var val = $(this).val()
    q.push($(this), function (err) {
        // this will be logged when the task is completed
        console.log('finished processing ' + val);
    });
});
```

Another way would be to use an array of [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)