# jQuery request a list of url while limit the max number of concurrent request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Queue AJAX calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4797566/queue-ajax-calls)

I have a list of id:

`var ids = [3738, 75995, 927, ... ]; // length is about 2000`

I'd like to request the url `http://xx/ + id` with `$.getJSON`, like:

```
ids.forEach(function(id, index){
    $.getJSON('http://xx/' + id, function(data){
        // store the data in another array.
    });
});
```

However, this will make too much requests in one time, making the browser blocking for a while, so my question is, how could I limit the number of concurrent ajax request in jQuery? for example, I send 10 request and when each of them got the response I send another request.

Comment: If the requests are passed as async, it won't lock the browser. If the $.getJSON function works like the $.ajax function, then all the calls are async and you should not worry about it

Comment: @Bruno Too many asynch request can bring down the browser as well

Comment: @Bruno but I can feel that the browser is obviously slow..

Comment: I believe you then must break your each loop every ten times and keep track of the times you already requested until you do everything you must do. But since I don't know if this is a good approach I'll leave this as a comment

Comment: The solution should be how can I make the backend handle multiple ids.

Comment: @epascarello I can't. This is an api from another website which I have no control over.

Comment: The other site is most likely going to block you/rate limit you if you make that many requests.

Answer (score 1):

`shift()` or `pop()` the ids off of the array as you start the requests.  Start by firing off 10 requests. Then in the `complete()` handler for your ajax call, check for an array length. If it's greater than 0, `setTimeout` for a few hundred milliseconds (to free up the browser a bit) and then shift or pop off another ID and fire another request.

Answer (score 1):

```
var $queue = $({});

ids.forEach(function(id, index) {
    $queue.queue("ajaxQueue", function( next ) {
        $.getJSON('http://xx/' + id, function(data){
            // store the data in another array.

            next();
        });
    });
});

$queue.queue("ajaxQueue", function() {
    // everything is saved
});

$queue.dequeue("ajaxQueue");
```

---

**jQuery docs:**

[jQuery.queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)
[jQuery.dequeue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)

**SO:**

[What are queues in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058158/can-somebody-explain-jquery-queue-to-me/3314877#3314877)

---

**Also:**

> The solution should be how can I make the backend handle multiple ids. – [epascarello](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14104/epascarello)

---

<s>##Ten request at the time:</s> Have some issues!

```
var $queue = $({}),
    handler;

ids.forEach(function(id, index) {
    if ( !(index % 10) && handler ) {
         $queue.queue("ajaxQueue", handler);
    }
    handler = (function(prev) {
        return function( next ) {
            prev();
            $.getJSON('http://xx/' + id, function(data){
                // store the data in another array.
            });
            if ( next ) {
                next();
            }
        }
    })(handler);
});

$queue.queue("ajaxQueue", function() {
    // everything is saved
});

$queue.dequeue("ajaxQueue");
```

**`x % y`**

```
(index % 10) => Math.floor(index/10)*10 === index;
!(index % 10) => Math.floor(index/10)*10 !== index;
```

Comment: Thanks, but how is this different from setting the async flag to false in jQuery?

Comment: `async:false` doesn't work cross-domain & freezes the entire application while making the request.

Comment: @wong2 see comment. Forgot to [at]you before.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
var current;    

function fetchCurrentLast()
{
    if (current < ids.length)
    {
        var id = ids[current];
        current++;

        $.getJSON('http://xx/' + id, function(data){
            // store the data in another array.

            fetchCurrentLast();
        });
    }
}

current = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    fetchCurrentLast();
}
```

Comment: @mplungjan: Yep, we wrote the same code. At least, I think that's what you're saying. If not, I don't know what you are saying.

Comment: But I'm doing the reccursive call in the *callback* function, which means it can only be done after the previous call is complete...

Comment: But you are not! You are calling the function 10 times fast and then again each time, so at least 20 times

Comment: I am calling it ten times to start off with, so that we do 10 at the same time, as per the question. This code works on arrays of sizes below 20 just fine, because of the `(current < ids.length)` check

Comment: Nope. Not convinced. I'm off to bed. Try your code for real

Comment: Let's change `for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)` into `for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)` and an empty array of ids, according to your logic it should go for at least 4 queries now. Let's see, for `i==0`: `current == 0`, `ids.length == 0`, `current < ids.length == false` as such, we don't go into the if of `fetchCurrentLast()` and as there is nothing outside the if, we don't do anything in that function. 0 requests sent so far. Then for `i==1` we get the exact same story, so again no requests and nothing that is going to happen later on. As far as I know, 0 requests is less than 4 requests

Answer (score 0):

```
var cnt = 0;
function getEach() {
    if (cnt>=ids.length) return;
    $.getJSON('http://xx/' + ids[cnt], function(data){
    // store the data in another array.
    cnt++;
    getEach(); 
    // or setTimeout(getEach,1000); to wait a sec
    // or if (cnt%10==0) setTimeout(getEach,1000); to wait a sec every 10
    //    else getEach();
  });
}
```

Comment: The `cnt++` is in the wrong place, as with this code one can only do one request at a time, not 10

Comment: This will do all requests one at a time each one when the previous finished as asked for in the original question

Comment: From the question: `for example, I send 10 request and when each of them got the response I send another request.`

Comment: MHmm I did not notice the 2000, but my code will work with or without batching

Comment: Because you update `cnt` only after the ajax request returns, when you use batching, you will be fetching the same result more than once. For example, if assuming each request takes exactly even long, you get ten times the result for `id = 0` and then ten times the result for `id=10` and so on (in reality they won't take equally long, so it becomes much more of a mess).

Comment: Not true. If you set cnt to 10, it will get 10-19 so batching will work

Comment: Okay I was mistakes, only the original 10 will be getting the same request. Still, that's a pretty major flaw.

Comment: I do not see the flaw. Another function is needed for the batching that isall

Comment: `getEach(); getEach()` does not work. Yes, `getEach(); cnt++; getEach(); cnt++;` does, but that's not trivial code, so in that case that code should be included in your answer. (And that's basically what I've been saying all along, except I used a different way to solve the same problem.

Comment: Replace the return with a callback to the batching function and it will work. Shees this is getting too long